# How to serialize property base on context Bean type when use jackson?

Tags: jackson, jackson-databind, jackson2

For a specific property type (such as MyType), I want to serialize it to diff output base on what Bean it define in.

```
class A {
  MyType t;
}

class B {
  MyType t;
}
```

Want to serialize A.t to value1, B.t to value2 base on the type of A or B. I found `ContextualSerializer`  interface `JsonSerializer<?> createContextual(SerializerProvider prov, BeanProperty property)`. The `BeanProperty` just can get the property type and name but no context Bean type info.

Pease help me to figure out the way?